# Communication between server running on remote host and client on ubuntu

Tags: client-server, ubuntu-14.04, ping, remote-server

I have imported a remote host in ubuntu from the ssh command. I am running a server.c code on the remote host and want to run the client.c code on the ubuntu terminal. The client code runs from the following lines of code:

```
./client host_name 2222
```

But both of the programs are running on their respective local hosts, so the following command

```
./client localhost 2222
```

will try to communicate with the localhost of the ubuntu machine because I want it to communicate with the local host?

Comment: I have also tried the command: ./client jack 2222 
But it gives the following error: ERROR, no such host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by turning off the firewall as it was blocking the communication over the network.